# Delete values between specific ranges of indices in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array :

```
Z = [1 24 3 4 52 66 77 8 21 100 101 120 155];
```

I have another array:

```
deletevaluesatindex=[1 3; 6 7;10 12]
```

I want to delete the values in array `Z` at indices (1 to 3, 6 to 7, 10 to 12) represented in the array `deletevaluesatindex`

So the result of `Z` is:

```
Z=[4 52 8 21 155];
```

I tried to use the expression below, but it does not work:

```
X([deletevaluesatindex])=[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
rdvi= size(deletevaluesatindex,1);   %finding rows of 'deletevaluesatindex'
temp = cell(1,rdvi);     %Pre-allocation

for i=1:rdvi
    %making a cell array of elements to be removed 
    temp(i)={deletevaluesatindex(i,1):deletevaluesatindex(i,2)};
end

temp = cell2mat(temp); %Now temp array contains the elements to be removed
Z(temp)=[]  % Removing the elements
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [**`bsxfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [**`cumsum`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
%// create index matrix
idx = bsxfun(@plus , deletevaluesatindex.', [0; 1])
%// create mask
mask = zeros(numel(Z),1);
mask(idx(:)) = (-1).^(0:numel(idx)-1)
%// extract unmasked elements
out = Z(~cumsum(mask))
```

---

```
out =    4    52     8    21   155
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control how `deletevaluesatindex` is generated, you can instead directly generate the ranges using MATLAB's colon operator and concatenate them together using

```
deletevaluesatindex=[1:3 6:7 10:12]
```

then use the expression you suggested

```
Z([deletevaluesatindex])=[]
```

If you have to use `deletevaluesatindex` as it is given, you can generate the concatenated range using a loop or something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/163153#answer_159326)

```
lo = deletevaluseatindex(:,1)
up = deletevaluseatindex(:,2)
x = cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1;up(:)-lo(:)+1]),[lo(:);0]-[0;up(:)]-1)+1);
deleteat = x(1:end-1)
```

Comment: I have control on how deletevaluesatindex is generated. if I have x=1,y=3, how can I concatenate them to become 1:3 and insert then to deletevaluesatindex. I cann't concatenate them as string, then I cann't use then in Z([deletevaluesatindex])=[]

Comment: `x:y` will generate `1 2 3`, so you can do `deletevaluesatindex = horzcat(deletevaluesatindex, x:y)`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** as in comments noted this solution only works in GNU Octave

with bsxfun this is possible:

```
Z=[1 24 3 4 52 66 77 8 21 100 101 120 155];
deletevaluesatindex = [1 3; 6 7;10 12];
idx = 1:size(deletevaluesatindex ,1);
idx_rm=bsxfun(@(A,B) (A(B):deletevaluesatindex (B,2))',deletevaluesatindex (:,1),idx);
Z(idx_rm(idx_rm ~= 0))=[]
```

Comment: it is giving the following error: Error using bsxfun
Invalid output dimensions.
Error on line
idx_rm=bsxfun(@(A,B) (A(B):deletevaluesatindex (B,2))',deletevaluesatindex (:,1),idx);

Comment: @ryh12 I tested in GNU Octave. online demo: http://rextester.com/OCUL14882

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thanks,answer updated, mentioned that it only works in Octave