# Create an index vector based on start and stop values

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

Based on a matrix which contains several rows of the beginning (first column) and the end (second column) of an interval of index, I would like to create a vector of all the index. For instance, if `A = [2 4; 8 11 ; 12 16]`, I would like to have the following vector `index = [2 3 4 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]`.

I'm looking for the fastest way to do that. For now, I found only two possibilities:

1) with a loop

```
index = [];
for n = 1:size(A, 1)
    index = [index A(n, 1):A(n, 2)];
end
```

2) with `arrayfun`

```
index = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) A(n, 1):A(n, 2), 1:size(A, 1), 'uni', 0));
```

Interestingly, `arrayfun` is much faster than the loop version, and I don't know why. Plus I use a conversion from cell to mat, so that's weird. What do you think about that? Do you have another suggestions?

Thanx for your help

Comment: The first sentence has been removed! It was Hello everyone ;) and sorry I made a mistake, the vector index would be equal to [2 3 4 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]

Comment: The first sentence was removed because it constitutes noise in your question, salutations are unnecessary. You can (and should) edit your question using the [edit] link under it. `arrayfun` is just a wrapper around a loop, the only reason it's faster is that you failed to pre-allocate in your loopy version, so in each iteration some (slow) memory allocation is going on.

Comment: @Divakar Your duplicate answer does not seem to give the right result

Comment: @thewaywewalk Ah thanks, was a bug indeed! Should be fixed now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the green check mark on the left to indicate the system that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell how fast that is, at least there is no looping:

```
A = [1,3;11,13;31,33;41,42;51,54;55,57;71,72];

%// prepare A
A = A.';

%// create index matrix
idx = bsxfun(@plus, A, [0; 1]);
%// special case: 54 and 55 are basically superfluous
%// need to be removed, but 71 and 72 shouldn't
A = A(:); 
dA = diff(A); dA(1:2:end) = 0;
idx = idx(~( [0;dA] == 1 | [dA;0] == 1 ));

%// create mask
mask = zeros(max(A),1);
mask(idx(:)) = (-1).^(0:numel(idx)-1);

%// index vector
out = find(cumsum(mask))
```

---

```
out.' =

      1  2  3 11 12 13 31 32 33 41 42 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 71 72
```

Comment: Very nice! Isn't writing `idx = [A(1,:); A(2,:)+1]` is much simpler/faster then calling `bsxfun`? Also you have a small typo in `infex`, and `out` is a column vector.

Comment: @EBH I'd say `idx = [A(1,:); A(2,:)+1]` is slower, but simpler - probably. out is a column vector, true, I just transposed it for displaying purposes.

Comment: your solution generates partial results please test with A =[1, 3;11,15;21,25;31,33;41,48; 51,54;61,67;71,72;81,82;91,94];

Comment: @thewaywewalk  seems that works!.added to the benchmark

Answer (score 2):

Here is a collection of methods:

**Method 1** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39422485/6579744 :

```
lo = A(:,1);
up=A(:,2);
index=cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1;up(:)-lo(:)+1]),[lo(:);0]-[0;up(:)]-1)+1);
index= index(1:end-1);
```

**Method 2:** this is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507276/6579744 . I  also provided the same answer but because Divakar's answer is before mine his (modified) answer preferred:

```
start_idx = A(:,1)';
end_idx = A(:,2)';
lens = end_idx - start_idx + 1;
shift_idx = cumsum(lens(1:end-1))+1;
id_arr = ones(1,sum(lens));
id_arr([1 shift_idx]) = [start_idx(1) start_idx(2:end) - end_idx(1:end-1)];
index = cumsum(id_arr);
```

**Method 3:** this is mine

```
N = A(:,2) - A(:,1) +1;
s=cumsum([ 1; N]);
index=(1:s(end)-1) -repelem(s(1:end-1),N) + repelem(A(:,1),N);
%octave    index=(1:s(end)-1) -repelems(s(1:end-1),[1:numel(N);N']) + repelems(A(:,1),[1:numel(N);N']);
```

**Method 4**: another naswer from this thread by [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605073/thewaywewalk)

```
A = A.';
idx = bsxfun(@plus, A, [0; 1]);
A = A(:); 
dA = diff(A); dA(1:2:end) = 0;
idx = idx(~( [0;dA] == 1 | [dA;0] == 1 ));
mask = zeros(max(A),1);
mask(idx(:)) = (-1).^(0:numel(idx)-1);
index = find(cumsum(mask));
```

**Method 5** your second method:

```
index = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) A(n, 1):A(n, 2), 1:size(A, 1), 'uni', 0));
```

**Method 6** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423102/6579744 :

```
sz= size(A, 1);
index_c = cell(1,sz);
for n = 1:sz
    index_c{n} = [A(n, 1):A(n, 2)];
end
index = cell2mat(index_c);
```

**Method 7** only works in Octave:

```
idx = 1:size(A ,1);
index_a =bsxfun(@(a,b) (a(b):A (b,2))',A (:,1),idx);
index = index_a(index_a ~= 0);
```

**Method 8** your first method:

```
index = [];
for n = 1:size(A, 1)
    index = [index A(n, 1):A(n, 2)];
end
```

**Test data:**

```
i= 1:500:10000000;
j= i+randi([1 490],1, numel(i));
A = [i', j'];
```

**Result** tested in Octave, in Matlab may be different

```
method1: 0.077063 seconds
method2: 0.094579 seconds
method3: 0.145004 seconds
method4: 0.180826 seconds
method5: 0.317095 seconds
method6: 0.339425 seconds
method7: 3.242287 seconds
method8: doesn't complete in 15 seconds
```

the code that used in bechmark is in [**Online Demo**](http://rextester.com/SGFWGE11375)

Comment: What is your code for benchmarking?

Comment: @thewaywewalk in online demo http://rextester.com/SGFWGE11375