# Assigning values in neighborhood of local maxima’s to the value of local maxima based on varying window width (non symmetric window width)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, max, signal-processing

This question is an extension of my previous question with some new issues so I thought to make a new query. I hope it is ok.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054811/changing-the-values-in-the-neighbourhood-of-local-maxima-to-the-local-maxima/46055833#46055833

**Query:**

- Where I find local maxima. I want to make a window and assign the values depending upon window size to the neighbors the value of local maxima.
- Problem: (I want my window size to change as in my original signal I have different behavior around local maxima’s.) For example in 8th window local maxima is at 34th location but I have assigned the values on the left of 34th location the value of local maxima.
- In short I want to have varying and controllable window width.

Please have a look at the attached picture to get an idea of output what I want.

I hope it will give some good idea.

I want to have varying and non symmetric means not same at every local maxima  window width .

I have also attached a code for nlfilter which is doing exactly what I want to do means it makes window and assign values to local maximas within that window width but I need to have flexible and changeable window width.

Is it possible to have varying window width or is there some other way possible to do that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMf70.png)

**Code:**

```
  t = 1:35 ; 
  Y = [1 3  13  6  2 7 5 4 2 4 1 0 1 2 3 5 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 6 7 0 0 8 0 1 1 2 3 4 2];

  n = 2;

  [p l] = findpeaks(Y);

  locations = zeros(size(Y));
  locations(l) = true;
  locations = conv(locations, ones(1, 2*n+1), 'same') > 0;

  X = -inf(size(Y)); % create temporary
  X(l) = Y(l); % copy the local maxima

  X = nlfilter(X, [1 2*n+1 ], @(x) max(x)); %replace all values with it local maxima
  X(l) = Y(l); % ensure local maxima are not changed
  Y(locations) = X(locations); % copy filtered temporary to output

  figure(1)
  hold on 
  plot(t,Y,'r')

  t = 1:35 ; 
  Y = [1 3  13  6  2 7 5 4 2 4 1 0 1 2 3 5 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 6 7 0 0 8 0 1 1 2 3 4 2];
  plot(t,Y,'b')

  hold off
```

I shall be grateful to you for your valuable replies.

**Further Explanation:**

Please have a look at the pictures attached.

2nd picture is  a part of original signal with local maximas mentioned as green dots.

In 1st pictures the red lines shows the region which I want to assign the value of local maxima. Green Dot is local maxima . So you will see that if I apply window with fixed width it will not work because the points before local maxima are less than after local maxima.

The reason for placing 1 outside in example  is same that there are few points before local maxima which I want to flat as compared to after local maxima.
The same is the case with other windows like last window 8 I have local maxima on 34th location but why I have chosen large values before it is only due to the values I want to assign the values of local maxima .

[image]
[image]

Comment: If some body has some suggestions please mention .. May be it will be helpful for me to approach the results.

Comment: Based on your attached example it is useful if you explain,window by window, how to get the output from the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot rahnema for your reply.
Actually I want to apply varying window and the concept is similar that where I will find local maxima I will apply window and flat the signal within that window width but the issue is now different window width.
I will speak the truth that I also do not have idea that how to reach the output so I placed query so if you have some good suggestion u please share with me. It will solve my issue.

Comment: Please explain how do you produce the output. I want to say that how with what criteria did you draw rectangles around the numbers.

Comment: This is the desired output that I want.
 P = 13 7 4    5   1    7   8   4 L =  3  6  10 16 19 25 28 34
Example (13 is at location 3  so from location 3 maxima location I want my window to extend 1 position to the left and 2 points to the right of local maxima means from location 3 window should be extended from location 2 3 4 5 . 
For 2nd window my maxima is at location 6 so I want window of width 1 here means just 1 location toward right and left of local maxima .
For window 8 my local maxima location is 34 but I have applied window ranging from location 30 to location 35.

Comment: Actually I need varying windows with varying widths and I am looking for the solution for that how to do this.
Inshort , I am looking for How to apply varying window with varying width on signals based on local maxima location.
Please let me know if my answer is still confusing.

Comment: As my original signal is too long so I am thinking to have a varying window width but do not know how to get this sorry.Can you please explain how? What I have tried is going in different direction that’s why I have not uploaded my findings to achieve this. I have taken the differential of signal and trying to apply for loop for that but unfortunately it’s far away from what I am expecting. So it will be really nice of you if help me out with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a criterion that starting form a peak and going to the both sides we compute variance of neighbors of the peak and we increase the radius of the neighborhood until variance of neighboring elements becomes greater than a predefined *threshold*.

Here `idx_peaks` is position of peaks  and `peaks` is value of peaks. After applying the threshold you can get number of elements before and after position of each peak `n_before` and `n_after`. Then you can [find indices of neighborhood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429966/6579744) and assign values to them.

```
Y = [1 3  13  6  2 7 5 4 2 4 1 0 1 2 3 5 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 6 7 0 0 8 0 1 1 2 3 4 2];
idx_peaks = [3 6 10 16 19 25 28 34];
peaks = [13 7 4 5 1 7 8 4];
threshold = 2;
cumvar = @(a)cumsum(a(:).^2)./(1:numel(a)).'-(cumsum(a(:))./(1:numel(a)).').^2;
categ = zeros(numel(Y),1);
categ(idx_peaks)=1;
forward_categ = cumsum(categ(idx_peaks(1):end));
n_after = accumarray(forward_categ,Y(idx_peaks(1):end),[],@(x)sum(cumvar(x)<threshold)-1).';
backward_categ = cumsum(flipud(categ(1:idx_peaks(end))));
n_before = flipud(accumarray(backward_categ,fliplr(Y(1:idx_peaks(end))),[],@(x)sum(cumvar(x)<threshold)-1)).';

lo = idx_peaks-n_before;
up = idx_peaks+n_after;
val = repelem(peaks,up-lo+1);
index=cumsum(accumarray(cumsum([1;up(:)-lo(:)+1]),[lo(:);0]-[0;up(:)]-1)+1);
index= index(1:end-1);
Y(index) = val
```

Here is the result when setting the threshold to 2 :

```
Y=
[1 3 13 6 2 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 7 7 0 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
```

Comment: thanks a lot rahnema 1 for ur time and great goodwill gesture. Just give me sometime to play with the code and will get back to u for qurries.Thanks a lot again..

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahnema 1 . This is a perfect code and concept what i want to do but issue is that in my original data I have 1*2173 locations and peaks and also my original data size is 1*1600000.
So it’s very very difficult to place n before and n after means values before and after from hand so is there any way that we can do this thing automatically rather than manually.

Comment: Rehnema 1 . I know but I placed an example here so that It will be easy for others to understand.
I want to do exactly this thing what you have done but for large data set and for that I am having some difficulty in placement of values before and after. Sorry for this as I did not placed whole data set here. It will be nice of you if you have some logic which works for large data set it will be great gesture and it will work for me as I mentioned that my try did not worked in right direction . Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Actually I want to make a window around local maxima but I want the width of window to be controllable because in my real data around local maximas signal behavior is not similar so this is possible by making a window with varying width around maxima so the local maxima where I want to change it by observing the signal I will be able to do that .

Comment: I can't get what you want except that you explain exactly how did you draw rectangles around the numbers.Please explain why the first element of the array `[1]` is outside the first window . Also you should have reasoning for all elements of the array. Please add your explanations to the question .

Comment: Just give me few minutes I will explain the whole details with reasoning.

Comment: Please have a look at the further explanation above and just a request please let me know if its fine with you.

Comment: Please let me know if I remained successful in making my idea clear to you.

I will wait .

Comment: You are relatively (not completely) successful, let me so I can post my answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot rahnema 1 for ur help and time . Take ur time.

Comment: Thanks a lot rahnema 1 A lot of thumbs up for u .. Just give me sometime I will play with the code and if i have some qurrey I will come back to u..

Comment: Instead of/Besides thumbs up you can [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or accept an answer!

Comment: already thumbs up and selected .... thanks a lot for ur help and time it is great good will gesture...many thumbs up for u....