# Indexing Blocks of Arrays

Tags: matlab

I have an array -

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,...,120]
```

I want to access elements,

```
 x(9),...,x(15)
```

and every 24th element thereafter.

E.G

```
   x(9),..., x(15) , x(33),...,x(39) , x(57),...,x(63)
```

and so on, up to

```
x(120).
```

Any other element Id like to be `0`, so that its looks something like this.

```
x = [0,0,...,0,0,x(9),...,x(15),0,0,...,0,0,x(33),...,x(39),0,0,...]
```

If there is a way to do this could I be given some help for a solution?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429966/create-an-index-vector-based-on-start-and-stop-values/39434045#39434045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of zeros and using a loop change its elements:

```
result = zeros(size(x));
for k =9:24:numel(x)
    result(k:k+6)=x(k:k+6);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I also wanted the elements in-between too. So `x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12),x(13),x(14),x(15)`.